# Place a $\star$ over a letter as an accent

Tags: vertical-alignment, accents

I want to create a stylized version of the i where the dot has been replaced by a $\star$.

[image: Startittle]

I know how to `stackrel`, but that's about the only thing I know about stacking things on top of eachother.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some low level TeX is the easiest way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\generic}{\textsf{Gener\istar c}}
\newcommand{\istar}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\hidewidth$\scriptstyle\star$\hidewidth\cr\i\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Large \generic

\normalsize \generic

\footnotesize \generic

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of the `accsupp` package you can make the text searchable and copyable as “Generic”. Unfortunately, not all PDF viewers support the feature.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{accsupp}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\generic}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{ActualText=Generic}\textsf{Gener\istar c}\EndAccSupp{}}
\newcommand{\istar}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\hidewidth$\scriptstyle\star$\hidewidth\cr\i\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Large \generic

\normalsize \generic

\footnotesize \generic

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know also if it is possible for the text to "behave" like "Generic" does?  By behave I mean copying/highlighting and searching.  That the textual representation is "Generic".

Comment: @PålGD That can be done with the `accsupp` package, but copying will only work with some PDF readers. If the PDF reader doesn't support the feature, there's nothing to do, as far as I know. I added the code.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is with a `stackengine` approach.  EDITED to use `\i` instead of `i`.

The vertical position of the star may be adjusted with the `.02\baselineskip` optional argument, and the horizontal position of the star may be adjusted with the `\mkern-.2mu` adjustment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\istar{\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackon[.02\baselineskip]{\i}{$\mkern-.2mu\scriptstyle\star$}}
\newcommand\generic{Gener\istar c}
\begin{document}
\generic\ \textsf{\generic}\par
\Huge\generic\ \textsf{\generic}\par
\footnotesize\generic\ \textsf{\generic}\par
\scriptsize\generic\ \textsf{\generic}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]